# WiseJ ColumnFilter Properties not showing in DataGridView "Edit Columns" options

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to integrate WiseJ's DataGridView Columnfilter extension into my WinForms app by following [their tutorial](https://wisej.com/blog/columnfilter/) but after I have installed the NuGet package and dropped a WiseJ 2 Column Filter toolbox object from the toolbox onto my winform, the properties under the "Misc" header don't show up when I click on "edit columns".

How can I get this to work? The column filter seems very convenient and looks like it takes care of the filtering part and the code that goes with it.

According to their tutorial, there should be a "Misc" part with more options under it.

**their Image**
[image]

**What mine looks like**
[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with the WiseJ 2 column filter and do not want to dissuade you from using it, however, I ran into the same issue you describe. I do want ask… What does the WiseJ 2 Column Filter offer that cannot be done by a “regular” filtering of the grids data source? In my small research on the WiseJ 2 Column filter, this appears to be a lot of extra work for simple sorting that can be easily done with a single LINQ statement or Row filter. My question is… Is there some “special” filtering you need that cannot be done by simply filtering/sorting the grids data source?

Comment: @JohnG, I am trying to make it so that the user can filter and sort like in excel. One of the ways I've found is to use the [advanced dataGridView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaZeeHRRCGA&t=67s) since it has a dropdown tab in the header however since i don't have a Datasource, I am finding it difficult. I stumbled upone the WiseJ column filter yesterday and thought it could be a viable option. I didnt think trying to filter without a datasource would be this difficult. I thought it would be more straight forward. If you know of any sources/tutorials that can help me do this, let me know.

Comment: @JohnG, I've found a lot of tutorials on how to filter and sort when there is a database attached, but i havent found much for when there is no datasource.

Comment: Can I ask why you choose NOT to use a data source for the grid? In almost all cases, including this one… NOT using a data source for the grid simply “creates” much more work for YOU and opens your code to more problems. I have used the `AdvancedDataGridView` in the past and it works OK and sounds like this may work for you. If the only thing preventing you from using it is that it only works when the grid uses a data source, then… create a data source. As I started, this should be done anyway simply to avoid unnecessary coding.

Comment: Lastly, In my research on the WiseJ 2 Column Filter, which was scarce, but… I have a strong suspicion that this is a control for a “WEB” application and not necessarily targeted to a `WinForms` application. Specifically, the `ColumnFilter` control is IN the `WiseJ.Web` namespace. I cannot say with 100% confidence that this is true, however my searches returned little help in relation to using this control on a winforms application. In addition my feeble efforts did not work. I got no errors, however, the grid never displayed.

Comment: @JohnG, to answer your question of "Can I ask why you choose NOT to use a data source for the grid?", it turns out it's because of my lack of inexperience :-/ . I just found out that it was necessary...my bad. Still learning since I've never dealt with them before. It turns out the trick is, from what I've found so far, is to first programmatically create a Datatable, create the columns, then add your data to that. Once that is done, you can then set the DataGridView's `datasource` to the Datatable. I'm still working out some kinks like how to add a checkbox but that's what I've found so far.

Comment: As for the `DataGridView` vs the `AdvancedDataGridView`, if you have a better way for a user to quickly sort and filter for data, I'm all ears. I didn't find a way to do it using a `DataGridView` unless it involved a bunch of textbox's to act as the filter.

Comment: It sounds like you are going down the right path. For a check box column in the grid… make the column in the `DataTable` a `bool` type column. This will automatically set the grid column as check box column in the grid. I will agree with you, creating the UI controls to do the filtering is something I would want to avoid. That is why… if you want something like Excels type filtering set to show when the user clicks on a header column, then YOU will have to implement this. That is why… IF the `AdvancedDataGridView` does what you want, then why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Wisej is not for winforms. It’s a web framework.  The column filter works with Wisej.Web.DataGridView.